# What should be the workflow for test management in JIRA

Tags: testing, development-process, workflows, jira, test-management

We are using Jira to track all our tickets and confluence for documentation. We intend to document the test cases covered on Confluence.

Here are a couple requirements:

1. Consider a **development ticket done and ready for release** only when all of the **relevant test cases have been written and approved**
2. It is usually the case that developer completes his tickets by end of the Sprint along with Unit test cases and QA writes the integration and microservicee2e tests in the backend repo and Application E2E test cases in the ApplicationE2ETests repo in the same sprint or next to one. FE, BE, and ApplicationE2ETests each have their own repository. Backendrepo contains the unit tests, integration tests, and microservicee2e tests.
3. Not every single development ticket will have the requirement for QA to write additional test cases as some tickets are just minor optimizations and chore that do not essentially change the test cases from the QA.
4. The CI-CD pipeline is triggered when the feature branch is merged into the develop branch after PR approval.

What should be the workflow here to ensure that all of the test cases(unit, integration, and e2e) are written when the development ticket gets ready for release.

Comment: What do you mean by "test management in Jira"? Are you using a tool like Zephyr or Xray to add a Test issue type and test case and execution functionality? Or are you just interested in making sure that the tests are developed properly as part of implementing the development ticket? Are you referring to manual or automated testing?

Comment: Also, are you under any kind of regulatory constraints regarding traceability, such as requirement to test case or test executions for releases or something similar?

Comment: @ThomasOwens I am referring to automated testing. Planning to use https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222843/aio-tests-test-management-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview in the future but not so concerned about that at the moment. Only concerned about the workflow to ensure the tests are implemented and tracked properly as are development tickets

Comment: @ThomasOwens we are required to have traceability of all you mentioned. This is a requirement for the project as we will be audited by customers as they want to see if we follow our own processes during development of our product. I'm sure Rory can elaborate as it relates to this project.

Answer (score 2):

The team would be the best place to go to figure out what the workflow should be, but there are a few things to consider.

The idea of "done done" is very important. If a development ticket is done only after all test cases have been written (or, I'm assuming, updated), reviewed, and approved, then it's important to ensure that the tests are also done in the same iteration as the development work. Even if that means that the team's capacity is reduced, it is better to have work fully finished. The team can use this slack to do other work, such as improving their skills or improving test coverage or automating (or improving the automation) for various aspects of the development/build/test/deploy cycle.

If, for some reason, some tests *must* be written by an independent QA, I would advise moving this to a separate team. Whatever you consider the "development team" should be able to have "done done" work every iteration. However, there are only rare cases that truly need independent QA and, more often than not, it leads to additional overhead caused by the silos and handoffs. The better thing to do would be to eliminate the distinction between "developer work" and "QA work". Even if the developer is focused on unit tests and QA is focused on the integration and end-to-end tests, they should help each other out.

Branch management can be a little tricky since there will be multiple pull requests into the different repositories. This is one of the reasons why I tend toward a monorepo, where the entire deployable system lives in a single repository, even if that's multiple services.

To make sure that all of the test cases are written and merged, I'd consider using Jira subtasks. This can help manage everything across repositories. Subtasks can add some overhead, but you can link pull requests to them. You don't need a subtask for the unit tests, since those should be in the same pull request as the code changes. However, creating subtask(s) for integration tests, microservice end-to-end tests, and application end-to-end tests may be helpful. There are ways to use Jira automation to transition issues based on subtasks to make sure that the parent ticket is reflective of all of the children subtasks.

If you're going to use a test case management tool, I would also recommend getting that in place sooner rather than later. This can help with any kind of traceability between the development work and the test cases. If the test cases are represented by tickets, it may also be a better use of time to link the test cases to the development ticket rather than using subtasks.